# New tab in Safari window from Cocoa and Scripting Bridge

Tags: cocoa, safari, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to create a new tab in a Safari window from Cocoa using Scripting Bridge. My code looks something like this:

```
SafariApplication *safari = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];

    if ([[safari windows] count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"No window found. Creating a new one.");
            SafariDocument *newDoc = [[[safari classForScriptingClass:@"document"] alloc] init];
            [[safari windows] addObject:newDoc];
            [newDoc release];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Seems we already have a safari window");
            SafariTab *newTab = [[[safari classForScriptingClass:@"tab"] alloc] init];
            [[[safari windows] objectAtIndex:0] addObject:newTab];
            [newTab release];
        }
```

The first part if the "if" works, creating a new window. Creating the tab does not. This gets me "-[SafariWindow addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...", so obviously that's not the way to do it. I can't figure out how windows, documents and tabs relate to each other in Safari. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Thor

Answer (score 2):

A-ha! Creating a tab in a window is:

```
SafariTab *newTab = [[[safari classForScriptingClass:@"tab"] alloc] init];
[[[[safari windows] objectAtIndex:0] tabs] addObject:newTab];
[newTab release];
```